# If all animals were to die, would all plants die too?

Tags: botany, zoology, photosynthesis

Humans and many other animals are able to breathe because plants produce more oxygen than they need. I was thinking if all animals died all of a sudden, then wouldn't plants die too. Eventually they would produce too much oxygen and wouldn't have enough carbon dioxide to go through photosynthesis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Animals are not the only organisms to [respire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_respiration) without [photosynthesizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosynthesis). Fungi, many other eukaryotes and many bacteria respire too (and do not photosynthesize).

Now, if all animals were to suddenly die, there would sure cause a drastic environmental change for plants. Whether or not that would lead all plants to extinction is untestable and it is therefore impossible to give a definite answer. This type of question would be better suited for [worldbuilding.SE](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com). I personally doubt all plants would disappear.

Comment: Is this an attempt at an answer, a migration vote or a personal opinion? Your answers are usually of much higher standard Remi.b! ;-)